# Changing aspx code behind property from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is there any way to change the value of a code behind property from JavaScript without using hidden-fields?

Comment: What you mean exactly by "code behind property"?

Comment: Code behind property means I have written a property on aspx.cs e.g. public bool IsConnected...

Comment: So AJAX is your only option, see the answer you already have for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it could not be done without sending request to server either by postback or ajax etc. This  could help you sending request to server [**using jquery Ajax**](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

If you want to change the value of some server control then it is possible with javascript.

**In html**

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

**In javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript>
     txtName = document.getElementById('<%= txtName.ClientId %>');
     txtName.value = "changed";
     alert(txtName.value);         
</script>
```

Comment: I agree, you dont will change any "code-behind property" without postback. So, assuming you dont want a full postback, ajax is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would say AJAX is the best answer for your problem.